# why AjaxForm is not working for me?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following form, what i want to do is, when people click on the Search button,
an request will file to server, and server will return a new set of result, and i will re-render the div to present the new result

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "DivToUpdate" }))
        {
            <div style="margin: 10px 50px 5px 50px;">
                @Html.TextBox("instrument", (string)ViewBag.DefaultInstrumentStr)
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        }
        <div id="DivToUpdate" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_InstrumentList", @Model);
            }
            else
            {
                <span>Loading ....</span>
            }
        </div>
```

Here is my controller implementation:

```
public ActionResult Search(string instrument)
        {
            // ... base on the input perform certain action to generate a list of result

            return PartialView("_InstrumentList", instruments);
        }
```

when i run it, after clicking the search, i will only see the partial view in the browser, the data does not update the div.

anyone has any idea what did i do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> anyone has any idea what did i do wrong?

You forgot to reference the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: when start debug in visual studio.. i got this error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'unobtrusive': object is null or undefined

and click continue.... still the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You must reference some script:

in MVC3(set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled true):

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

in MVC2 and MVC3(set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled false):

```
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
```

For the differents,you can look at this:[Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Comment: hmmm in debug.. the request is filed to server.. but the div is not re-drawed... do i miss anything?

Comment: forgot to say.. thx for you advice... i added the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js .. and the ajax request seems to work.. just my page is not updated

Comment: my bad.. i set the display to none myself

Answer (score 0):

The `div` which you are trying to update, must be inside `Ajax.BeginForm` brackets.

Comment: Describe what are you actually get ? Did you look at request/response by firebug or fiddler ? Can you enter to the method in debug mode ?